# select2 custom matcher toUpperCase not defined

Tags: jquery-select2

I am trying to use a custom matcher with the select2 plugin but I'm getting an error "text.toUpperCase()" is not defined. I have followed the examples but can't get it to work. Any help would be appreciated. My code is as follows:

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.selectpicker').select2({
    placeholder: 'Select an option',
    matcher: function(term, text) {
      var has = true;
      var words = term.toUpperCase().split(" ");
      for (var i =0; i < words.length; i++){
        var word = words[i];
        has = has && (text.toUpperCase().indexOf(word) >= 0); 
      }
      return has;
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: what version are you using: v4 or v3?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're using v3 as from your matcher signature.

I'd suggest to normalize input arguments to make sure they are strings:

```
matcher: function(term, text) {
  var has = true;
  var words = ("" + term).toUpperCase().split(" ");
  for (var i =0; i < words.length; i++){
    var word = words[i];
    has = has && (("" + text).toUpperCase().indexOf(word) >= 0); 
  }
  return has;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using V4 as defined in the JS script source url. I will try your idea of normalising the content first. Not sure why it wasn't working though as it followed the examples.

What makes you think the matcher signature is wrong?

Comment: because default matcher has different signature:
    function matcher (params, data) {
      // Always return the object if there is nothing to compare
      if ($.trim(params.term) === '') {
        return data;
      }